# Virtualbox and Squid

Tags: proxy, squid

I'm trying to setup Squid and am having great difficulty (I'm new to all this). Basically, I have a VirtualBox machine which I can ssh in to (eamorr@192.168.56.101). I want this machine (192.168.56.101) to act as a transparent Squid caching server for my host machine.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be most appreciated. Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Is VirtualBox relevant to the question? Did you Google for a Squid getting started guide? (There are hundreds of Squid tutorials that will show you how to set it up on whatever distro you're using and others that will go through basic to advanced configurations).

Comment: Not sure if VirtualBox is relevant to the question. In the absence of a VM from my sysAdmin, I'm just going to go ahead and use VirtualBox instead so as to simulate another machine which lies before my host machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set it up as a transparent proxy server if it is not connected to the network "before" your host machine.

Well, there is one way. If you have a manageable firewall (other than a standard router) in front of your local network, then you could force all connections on certain ports to go through your virtual machine.

You can use it as a parallel one though.

Comment: Maybe I'd be better off using a VM, rather than VirtualBox? Then I could set my machine's gateway address to that of the VM.

Comment: If you are required to add settings to your local machine, then it is still not really a transparent proxy.   A transparent proxy is there regardless of the client settings.

Comment: Yes. I'm an electronics engineer and have been thrown in at the deep end on this one. I think I need to read up on networking a bit more. Is the proxy transparent if it serves pages off 192.168.254.1 or something?

Comment: The proxy is transparent if all traffic is routed through it regardless of the settings on your clients. You can't just give it a specific IP address and then your problem is solved. You need to look into networking and how to design your network to work with a transparent proxy.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I think my question is a bit premature until I look into things a bit deeper.

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you get it figured out :)